# way for converting capital ascii codes to lower case ascii codes

Tags: javascript, jquery, ascii, fromcharcode

I need to efficiently convert the code of a capital char to its correspondent code in lower case.
ie: Convert the ascii code 97 to 65.  Corresponding to "A" and "a"

- An wrong answer may be just to add or sustract 32 to that integer. This would only work for an standard English keyboard.

  Consider accented, non-English, double-byte, etc chars
  ie: Ñ=165 / ñ=164 , Ç=128 / ç=135
- so far I am achieving it with this long detour:

  ```
  var myCapitalCode=65;
  var myLowerCode = String.fromCharCode(myCapitalCode).toLowerCase().charCodeAt()
  ```

Comment: Sounds like you already found your answer. What's the problem now?

Comment: Parsing it from ascii to char and from char to ascii again looks not very efficient.
I believe there must be a better way to do it.

Comment: It's straightforward. It's exactly what you meant to do: convert code to character, lowercase it, convert to code. The code is clear and functional.

Comment: "*Looks not very efficient*" - have you measured it? Do you have [actual performance problems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Premature_optimisation)? The only alternative I see was to download the Unicode character database, extract lowercase mappings from it, and store the charcodes in a huge lookup table (array).

Comment: thanks Bergi.
Maybe is beginners insecurity I just thought I wasnt able to find an existing function.

Comment: There *is* no existing function indeed. JS does not have an extra character datatype, only strings - characters are just strings of length 1. Lowercasing is intrinsically a string operation, not one on numbers (char codes).